# sqrt function weird behaviour in Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, while-loop, sqrt, square-root

In Python, I wrote a custom code sqrt(x, delta) to calculate the square root of a given number with a delta-close approximation. It uses a while loop and a binary-search-like algorithm.
The code:

```
from __future__ import division

def sqrt(x, delta):
    start = 0
    end = x
    while (end-start) > delta:
        middle = (start + end) / 2
        middle_2 = middle * middle
        if middle_2 < x:
            start = middle
            print "too low"
        elif middle_2 > x:
            end = middle
            print "too high"
        else:
            return middle
    result = (start + end) / 2
    return result
```

It basicly works and it is quite fast, but there are cases when it gets into an infinite while-loop.
Examples:

```
sqrt(1e27, 1/1024) => works fine (returns 'too low's and 'too high's, then returns correct result)
sqrt(1e28, 1/1024) => works fine
sqrt(1e29, 1/1024) => never-ending loop, it keeps printing 'too low' forever
sqrt(1e30, 1/1024) => works fine
sqrt(1e31, 1/1024) => 'too low' forever
sqrt(1e32, 1/1024) => works fine
sqrt(1e33, 1/1024) => works fine (also surprising after the problem with 1e29 and 1e31)
sqrt(1e34, 1/1024) => works fine
sqrt(1e35, 1/1024) => 'too low' forever
sqrt(1e36, 1/1024) => works fine
sqrt(1e37, 1/1024) => 'too high' forever (too high this time!)
sqrt(1e38, 1/1024) => works fine
sqrt(1e39, 1/1024) => works fine (surprising again..)
... 1e40-1e45 ... they all work fine
sqrt(1e46, 1/1024) => 'too low' forever (surprisingly it occurs now with 1e'even number')
...
sqrt(1e200, 1/1024) => works fine
sqrt(1e201, 1/1024) => works fine
...
sqrt(1e299, 1/1024) => 'too low' forever
sqrt(1e300, 1/1024) => 'too high' forever
...
sqrt(1e304, 1/1024) => 'too high' forever
sqrt(1e305, 1/1024) => works fine
... 305-308 ... they allwork fine
sqrt(1e309, 1/1024) => inf (reached some 'infinite' limit?)
```

I first thought it was with numbers above a limit, like 1e20.. But then it worked with them as well. Also, I had this thought that is was about 1e'odd' or 1e'even' numbers, but as we can see in the examples, it wasn't that. I also tried it using different delta's instead 1/1024, but they showed similar behavior.
 
I would appreciate any explanation that tells what is going on behind the scenes that causes this behavior.

Comment: 1/1024 is 0 it is always zero ... this is because you are doing integers ... try 1.0/1024

Comment: You should read about floating point accuracy. Here's a good start: http://randomascii.wordpress.com/2012/02/25/comparing-floating-point-numbers-2012-edition/

Comment: Joran, it is solved by "from __future__ import division"

Comment: `1e309` by itself evaluates to `inf` -- see any IEEE-754 specification.

Comment: ahh ok sorry ... you are all correct :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`float` can only represent a finite set of numbers. Your code ends up in a situation where `start` and `end` are two consecutive such numbers. As a result, `(start + end) / 2` has to be either rounded down to `start` or rounded up to `end`.

If it gets rounded down, `middle_2 < x`. Now, if `end - start > delta`, you've got a "too low" infinite loop.

If it gets rounded up, and if `end - start > delta`, you've got a "too high" infinite loop.

You should probably redefine `delta` as a relative error rather than an absolute one.

Comment: Thank you! I considered your explanation, and inserted a little modification which seems to have solved the problem. In the while-loop, before going into the if-elif-else part, I inserted an
"if middle==start or middle==end: return (start+end)/2"
modification and now it seems to work.